# Wocommerce Products appearing in tiered column

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, layout

I have just taken over a woocommerce store from another dev. He has used 'Flatsome' theme and page builder to build the website. I have seen an issue on some new products that I have added since taking over.

I created a new Category called 'Mini Platters' with a series of Sub Categories such as 'Breakfast Mini Platters' etc. All my products are reflecting on the front end, however the layout in the catalog is wrong. The products should be shown in a series of rows such as

[] [] []
[] [] []

but are instead appearing in a tiered column like this:

[  ]
[ ]
[]

I cannot see any CSS, PHP or any setting that is causing this. It is only happening on the new product category I created, and on none of the products that he created. the problem can be seen [here](https://www.foodplatters.co.za/product-category/mini-platters/breakfast-mini-platters). I have reached out to the theme creators with no luck as yet. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Devs use wordpress themes? And get paid doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing closing div tag in your templates. Double check them :) To be precise you are missing 3 closing divs :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing div in this location:

```
   <div class="badge callout badge-circle">
        <div class="badge-inner callout-new-bg is-small new bubble">NEW</div>
   </div>
   </div> //REMOVE THIS DIV
   <div class="product-small box ">
```